# Inserting a newline character with redirection in Batch

Tags: batch-file, redirect

### EDIT: Fixed! Changing grep to find fixed the newline issue.

I'm trying to output newline characters to a results file when I'm running a script to log test results. After every test result, I want the script to output a newline character for proper formatting.

The command I'm sending is:

```
tester.bat | grep "Passed all trials" > results.txt
```

It works properly, but it outputs like this inside results.txt:

```
Test #1: Passed all trialsTest #2: Passed all trials
```

and so on.

I'd like it to output like this inside results.txt:

```
Test #1: Passed all trials (newline)
Test #2: Passed all trials
```

Can it be done in a single line? If not, I'm open to longer solutions. If this is not possible, I guess I could write a separate script that will update the text file with appropriate newlines between "trialsTest," but this route is not preferable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `tester.bat|find "Passed all trials"` Does that work?

Comment: Why are you using grep? Find or findstr would work just fine.

Comment: changing grep to find fixed it. Thank you very much, both of you! How can I mark this question as answered?

Comment: You can mark this question as answered by accepting the answer, since it solved the problem; you should *not* include an answer in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why using external utilities, when there are built-in function that do exactly what you Need?

```
tester.bat|find "Passed all trials"
```

or

```
tester.bat|findstr /c:"Passed all trials"
```